# Creating an integer 2d array (as compared to a string 2d array) without mentioning the dimension

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, stack

I was trying to create a `2d array` without mentioning the dimensions like as follows:

```
int m1[][] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

I got the following error when compiled:

```
error: array type has incomplete element type
```

Is it not possible to create a `2d array` on the `stack` (as opposed to dynamic memory allocation on `heap`) without mentioning the `row` and `column`?

If compiler can't determine the dimension for an integer 2d array, how does it determines the space requirement for string 2d array. For example,

```
char *keywords[] = {"auto", "static", "extern", "volatile"};
```

Comment: After a bit of afterthought, I just have to say this: **Don't be lazy!** You just need to put _two_ numbers; actually you only need _one_! Is it really that big of a deal, when you already writing out the whole array?

Comment: @Anthales I just did that! ;)

Comment: Actually, I did that after reading this - http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html

Comment: Just skipped over it and didn't find much relation between it and your question..

Comment: I mean if it is a global array, you don't need to pass it to a function, and if it isn't, it's quite clear you need to pass the dimensions. In general: Just `#define` the dimensions - especially when you need to `extern` the array. So... any more question?

Comment: Actually, its part of the bigger problem that I'm working on.. So as of now, just #defining the dimension and moving on.. And, yes, I need to deal with multiple 2d arrays and keeping them as global is not advised and so need to pass/return 2d arrays to/from functions..

Comment: Actually returning arrays from functions is something you cannot do in C - you'd need to pass a second array (actually a pointer) and write into it. But this is getting offtopic; is your actual question answered? If yes, you can accept an answer and if you have another question, open a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ommit the outer dimension, but not the inner. So this is okay

```
int m1[][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

---

To your second question: `char *keywords[]` is NOT a 2d array! It is an array of pointers. Pointers are not arrays; Arrays are not pointers! (It's only that arrays *decay* into pointers to the first element of an array, if used as an rvalue).

Update: To actually answer your question: The strings will typically be statically "allocated" in readonly storage (for example directly written in object files/your program). So it's also wrong to declare your array as `char *[]` - it should be a `const char *[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, b/c the compiler would a) have no way of determining how much space to allocate and b) have no way of determining where a given element was located within the array.

Comment: The compiler _could_ check if all inner lists are of the same size and then take this as the inner dimension - it's just, that compilers are lazy (and that the standard doesn't enforce, or rather allow this).

Comment: @Anthales they are not lazy, this is perfectly valid code: `int m1[][3] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};`

Comment: Yes, this is valid. I'm not arguing that. Why do you think I'm arguing this?

Comment: @Anthales Didn't mean to offend you. I belive that if compilers would do that kind of guesswork it would open the door for a very subtle and hard to find class of bugs.

Comment: As long as the initialized number of values i.e. the `rows` and `columns` are consistent, the compiler should be able to work with it. Only if the given initializer has inappropriate `row` and `column`, the compiler can throw an error.

Comment: Yes, my point. The thing is that it's **not in the C/C++ standard**. Therefore one is not allowed to ommit the inner dimension.

Comment: The problem is maintainability. If the required dimension is not specified and a maintainer changes the "data", then a) there is no sign that code has to be changed somewhere else and b) the intended dimensions might be nowhere documented. I'd much rather like the compiler to throw an error on me and require me to put in the dimensions.

Comment: I agree that the problem is maintainability, but I'm not so sure about having "no sign that code has to be changed", since you probably would get the dimension per `sizeof`, therefore change would be implicit - of course I'm assuming no `extern`, one file. But yeah, most of the times it's no good idea to not fix the dimensions when you are statically initializing anyways...